# Django MySQL error creating tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've a similar problem as [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18256) raised on Django forum. How do I solve this issue??

I also have a User model extended, as follow:-

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
```

But I dont think the problem is with the model, because even if I remove the app containing the model from the `INSTALLED_APPS` list, and run the `manage.py migrate` command, it still throws the same errors, ie

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'db.#sql-456_113' (errno: 150)")
```

Without including any of the apps, it works fine. Any lead will be really helpful.

Comment: have u used python manage.py syncdb command??

Comment: It has been deprecated, hence not used. I directly applied `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Well, I tried `python manage.py makemgration appname` and then `python manage.py migrate` and it worked. But I have to do `python manage.py makemgration appname` for each and every app. How do I makemigrate all apps at once. ??

Comment: `python manage.py makemgrations`

Comment: For the very first time. I follow these steps. First step:-  `python manage.py makemigrations`. It says `No changes detected` . Then second step `python manage.py migrate`. It creates all the tables, and halts in between throwing  the same error which I've pointed out in the question.

Comment: Doing makemigration for every single app and then running `migrate` works for me. But then, does this needs to be done for every single app? What if I'd 20-30 apps. `makemigration` on all apps isnt a feasible solution.

Comment: There has to be a solution which makemigrates all the apps at once.

Answer (score 2):

Check the storage engine of your db tables. As refered [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18256) old MySQL used MyISAM which is incompatible with actual InnoDB storage engine. so, if your db has different storage engines for different tables and you try to make a Foreign Key, you will probably find this error. At least, this was my case :)
hope this helps someone