# Django Migration: Can't create table errno: 150

Tags: django, django-models

I have a brand new MariaDB serve (version: 5.5.41-MariaDB) and created a new database for my Django (1.8.2) application. The database was created using innoDB by default.

I have a **model** that looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)  # django's default user model
```

When I run python manage.py **migrate**. I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/vagrant/envs/leo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/vagrant/envs/leo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'leo.#sql-bcd_1f' (errno: 150)").
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Take a look to my answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447863/django-mysql-error-creating-tables/37397470#37397470
Maybe someone can use my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by downgrading to Django 1.7.9. It worked straight away after downgrading

Answer (score 4):

This error can also occur when you don't make the migration files. Be sure to run `makemigrations` before actual migration.

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem under django 1.8, the only difference is that I'm using MySQL and not MariaDB.

Changing the database's encoding from utf8_unicode_ci to utf_general_ci solved the problem for me.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This bizarre MySQL error is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018584/error-code-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150).  I'm not sure how your Django app is triggering it though.

Comment: I had the same issue when running `./manage.py migrate`.
There were all MyISAM tables in my DB but default engine was set to InnoDB.
Thus all new tables would be created as InnoDB what led to the `1005` error.

Answer (score 0):

OneToOneField doesn't need unique attribute, just like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Comment: I tried it without the unique=True attribute but have the same problem

Comment: Is there any other models in your project or app?

Comment: yes, but i commented them all out to troubleshoot, no luck